# Running python using java

Tags: java, python-3.x, jython-2.7

How to fix the below error in java?

Requirement: Running python program using java

supporting lib:jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar

python installed: python 3.6.0

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Hello world!!");
    //option 1
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); //ouput will be stored here

    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();

    context.setWriter(writer); //configures output redirection

    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

    interpreter.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('C:\\Users\\johns\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\python\\python36\\Lib\\site-packages')");
    engine.eval(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\johns\\Desktop\\python\\pytest.py"), context);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
//option 2
   // String execCmd = execCmd("python 
C:\\Users\\johns\\Desktop\\python\\pytest.py");
   // System.out.println("From Cmd Prompt" + execCmd);

}

public static String execCmd(String cmd) throws java.io.IOException {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    java.io.InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String val = "";
    if (s.hasNext()) {
        val = s.next();
    } else {
        val = "";
    }
    return val;
}
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major' in <script> at line number 1
at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:202)
at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:42)
at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:47)
at pythonproj.PythonProj.main(PythonProj.java:47)
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<script>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\johns\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\Lib\site- 
packages\pytesseract\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .pytesseract import (
File "C:\Users\johns\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\Lib\site- 
packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 10, in <module>
from PIL import Image
File "C:\Users\johns\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\Lib\site- 
packages\PIL\Image.py", line 31, in <module>
from ._util import py3
File "C:\Users\johns\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\Lib\site- 
packages\PIL\_util.py", line 3, in <module>
py3 = sys.version_info.major >= 3
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'

at org.python.core.Py.AttributeError(Py.java:205)
at org.python.core.PyObject.noAttributeError(PyObject.java:1013)
at org.python.core.PyObject.__getattr__(PyObject.java:1008)
```

Advice which is preferable approach to run the python program with jython or by calling command process as option 2 in  above code

Answer (score 2):

It seems the exception you are getting is caused by [a jython bug](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2380) (that is apparently fixed with jython-2.7.1).

Regarding your other question; if all you want to do is run the script and not interact with the interpreter in any way, and you know a suitable python version is installed on the system, using a process would probably be a lot easier and avoid this and potential other problems with jython.

Answer (score 0):

Since jython project is inactive and not python 3 so not up-to-date (see comments), your option2 to launch python.exe as a system executable is the good one.

It can't work the way you coded it because Runtime.exec doesn't execute a DOS Cli but directly an executable. So what you launch is python.exe, and your py file is an argument of this command

Here is an approach for launching it

```
public static String execPython(String pythonFile) throws java.io.IOException {

    // modification here: provide a String array with "python" as first argument, 
    // you may add other argument of your python program

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"python",pythonFile});

    java.io.InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String val = "";
    if (s.hasNext()) {
        val = s.next();
    } else {
        val = "";
    }
    return val;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String stdStream = execPython("C:\\Users\\johns\\Desktop\\python\\pytest.py");
        System.out.println(stdStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the information that jython was discontinued?

Comment: TBH I don't know what is the very last version from these 2 contradictive informations: http://www.jython.org/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython, but the fact is that  last version 2 is quite old, don't rely on bug fix for this version, and to me the current python is python 3, and jython3 was never released from the information I get, but from the offical site, the last jython3 news is too old (May 2013!) to consider it active

Comment: I see. You're right, jython.org seems outdated. It looks like jython 2.7.1 was only published on maven central and I also don't see any recent activity towards jython 3, but it doesn't seem to be officially discontinued either.

Comment: Yes it is more inactive than discontinued, It can restart if new contributors come, We can't really know with open projects, I will edit my post with that information.

Comment: `Runtime.exec(String)` doesn't run CMD (unless you explicitly tell it to) but it _does_ split the string at whitespace and take the first token as the programname (searched in the same fashion as CMD) which for this particular case is sufficient.